# Is there a way to get the target element on ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have an ng-repeat of textareas
and I need to access the target element on the ng-change callback

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
  <textarea ng-change="$ctrl.changed()"></textarea>
</div>
```

since I can't use $event, is there any other way to access the target element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding an `ng-focus` on the textarea

```
<textarea ng-change="$ctrl.changed()" ng-focus="$ctrl.setFocusedElement($event)"></textarea>

setFocusedElement (event) {
  $scope.focusedInput = event.target
}
```